# SharePoint Power Shell scripts run through Task Scheduler

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I have a script.ps1 file which contain the logic of run email notification Workflow and its working fine on execution with SharePoint Power Shell.

**How should I link my script.ps1 file with Windows Task scheduler? So I will run this workflow every day.**

And script.ps1 scripts supported with only SharePoint Powershell not Windows Power Shell.

Answer (score 1):

Create the scheduled task and set the action to:

- Program/Script: `Powershell.exe`
- Arguments: `-File "C:\script.ps1"`

If you got issue with `- File` only use `&'c:\script.ps1'`

[image]

Comment: The answer does not tackle any permission issues a script running against Sharepoint will surely meet.